# "'omp.h' file not found" when compiling using Clang

Tags: c++, linux, openmp, clang++

I'm trying to set up an OpenMP project using Clang (3.7.0) on my laptop running [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint).

Now I've read that OpenMP is not supported right away so I followed the tutorial https://clang-omp.github.io/ to integrate OpenMP into Clang.

I've cloned the source code, set the environment variables and set the *-fopenmp* flag to my project, but I still get the error:

> fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found

when building.

My guess is that I have set the environment variables wrong. Is there a way to check if I have put them in the right place? I have just copied them in the [.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) file.

When I run `locate omp.h` I get:

```
/usr/include/re_comp.h
/usr/include/linux/ppp-comp.h
/usr/include/linux/seccomp.h
/usr/include/net/ppp-comp.h
/usr/include/openssl/comp.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/omp.h
/usr/lib/perl/5.18.2/CORE/regcomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/arch/arm/include/asm/seccomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/arch/microblaze/include/asm/seccomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/arch/mips/include/asm/seccomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/arch/powerpc/include/uapi/asm/seccomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/arch/s390/include/asm/seccomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/arch/sh/include/asm/seccomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/arch/sparc/include/asm/seccomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/arch/x86/include/asm/seccomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/include/linux/ppp-comp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/include/linux/seccomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/include/net/ipcomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/include/uapi/linux/ppp-comp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/include/uapi/linux/seccomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/include/config/seccomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/include/config/crypto/pcomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/include/config/inet/ipcomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/include/config/inet6/ipcomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/include/config/isdn/ppp/bsdcomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/include/config/ppp/bsdcomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/include/config/xfrm/ipcomp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/include/linux/ppp-comp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/include/linux/seccomp.h
```

Here is my makefile:

```
# Requires the following project directory structure:
#  /bin
#  /obj
#  /src

# Use 'make remove' to clean up the whole project

# Name of target file
TARGET     = main

CXX        = clang++
CFLAGS     = -std=c++11 \
             -Weverything -Wall -Wextra -Wold-style-cast -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual \
             -Wno-missing-braces -Wempty-body -Wno-error=uninitialized \
             -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wno-c++98-compat \
             -pedantic-errors -pedantic \
             -Os -fopenmp

LINKER     = clang++ -o
LFLAGS     = -Wall -Weverything -pedantic

SRCDIR     = src
OBJDIR     = obj
BINDIR     = bin

SOURCES   := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
INCLUDES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS   := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

RM         = rm -f

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

.PHONEY: prepare
prepare:
    mkdir -p bin
    mkdir -p obj

.PHONEY: clean
clean:
    @$(RM) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Cleanup complete!"
    @$(RM) tmp_file-*
    @echo "Temporary files removed!"

.PHONEY: remove
remove: clean
    @$(RM) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
    @echo "Executable removed!"


.PHONEY: run
run:
    ./bin/$(TARGET)
```

Comment: Where exactly is that tutorial on https://clang-omp.github.io/? Is it [this one](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/index.html)?

Answer (score 9):

**OpenMP is well supported in Clang 3.7**, but you might need to enable it see [here](http://llvm.org/releases/3.7.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#openmp-support).

> OpenMP 3.1 is fully supported, but disabled by default. To enable it,
> please use the -fopenmp=libomp command line option.

Also see [Status of supported OpenMP constructs](https://github.com/clang-omp/clang/wiki/Status-of-supported-OpenMP-constructs) for more precision.

So you don't have to clone the *clang-omp* project any more.

What build system do you use for your project and what errors do you get when you compile?

If you use **Makefile**: do not forget to add the `-fopenmp` flag.

If you use [CMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake): you should also look for right OpenMP flags with the [FindOpenMP module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindOpenMP.html) and add them accordingly.

If you still get the include error, then your omp.h header file may not be in the Clang default search path. So you should try to include the one that comes with GCC and add `-I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/`.

So in your case you should add this line:

```
CFLAGS = -std=c+11 [etc...]
CFLAGS += -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/
LINKER = [etc...]
```

Comment: I build with a Makefile. and the only error I get is "src/main.cpp:6:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include <omp.h>" .  Also where do I need to put the -fopenmp=libomp command line option? I didnt understand

Comment: Please provide your Makefile some includes seem to be missed  and also verify that your PATH is correct. I ll add an answer.

Answer (score 4):

'omp.h' is a C header that comes with the "Mint" *libgcc-[version]-dev* ([RPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager)-based OSes have this header in a different package, e.g. libgomp-*).

Example *libgcc-4.8-dev*: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/omp.h

Solution: Install the version for your default GCC: `gcc --version`

[libgcc-dev](/questions/tagged/libgcc-dev)

Comment: OpenMP is supported in recent versions of Clang and GCC now.

Comment: Suggest : CFLAGS=-I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include

Answer (score 2):

In case the context is a build of Clang from source - one solution is to:

1. Ensure the `openmp` subproject is built by adding it to `LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS` at CMake invocation
2. Build that subproject with `cmake --build . --target omp`
3. Copy the generated `omp.h` from build/projects/openmp/runtime/src/omp.h to build/lib/clang/10.0.0/include, which is in the newly-built Clang's default search path.

I previously used the "add GCC's path to omp.h to every build command" approach, but I found this easier.