# fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found

Tags: macos, openmp

I'm trying to compile my OpenMP program, but it doesn't work, this error message shows:

```
 fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
```

I've tried the solutions for this problem here, but nothing worked with me.
please help
I'm Mac user

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400462/omp-h-file-not-found-when-compiling-using-clang?rq=1 Which compiler do you use?  Which flags? And which language?

Comment: gcc with c language. I don't understand what do you mean by flags

Comment: Did you install `gcc` with `homebrew`?

Comment: yes I did install it with homebrew

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to reinstall with:

```
brew reinstall gcc --without-multilib
```

Then you need to make sure you use the `homebrew` version of `gcc` (rather than anything Apple supplies) by running `gcc-5` rather than plain `gcc`. You can check its name and version by running the following because `homebrew` normally always installs everything to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
ls /usr/local/bin/gcc*
```

Finally, you need to add the `-fopenmp` flag to your compiler invocation to tell the compiler to do the OpenMP thing.

So, your command will look like:

```
gcc-5 -fopenmp program.c -o program
```

Comment: when I try to reinstall it this error occurs: Error: You must `brew link gmp mpfr libmpc isl' before gcc can be installed

Comment: Not sure what that means. I would remove them with `brew rm gmp mpfr libmpc isl` and then try reinstalling `gcc` and then, if necessary, reinstall the others. Maybe remove `gcc` too... `brew rm gcc` then fresh install `gcc`.